# I am not able to set selection limit in primeNg Angular6 multiselect drop-down

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

I am using `PrimeNG` and I am not able to limit the selection from dropdown values. Please help.

**Component:**

```
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/api';

interface City {
    name: string,
    code: string
}

export class MyModel {

cities1: SelectItem[];

cities2: City[];

selectedCities1: City[];

selectedCities2: City[];

constructor() {
    //SelectItem API with label-value pairs
    this.cities1 = [
        {label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}},
        {label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}},
        {label:'London', value:{id:3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN'}},
        {label:'Istanbul', value:{id:4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'}},
        {label:'Paris', value:{id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}}
    ];

    //An array of cities
    this.cities2 = [
        {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
        {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
        {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
        {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
        {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
    ];
}

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" formControlName="selectedCities"></p-multiSelect>
```

How can I use the `selectionLimit` attribute here to limit the number of checkBoxes

Please refer https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share us what you have tried so far. share your code here, so we can help you to solve your problem

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: @Salomon Zhang  ,Bear Nith codeis taken from offical primeNg site. how to implement it in my project

Answer (score 10):

You can use [selectionLimit] to limit the selection for ex:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities2" [selectionLimit]="2" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities2" optionLabel="name"></p-multiSelect>
```

In above example you can select only two items.

See the following  stackBlitz example

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-multiselect-limit-selection)

Comment: hi @Jeyam..Thanks for the response..i am not able to check the box in above stackBlitz

Comment: @saurabhmalviya I have updated my stackblitz, now you can click the stackblitz link and check it.

Comment: @saurabhmalviya Cheers Up!!